# How can i redirect to new window in sweet alert

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, sweetalert

How to open a url in new window in sweet alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)" for open in other window. Example:

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You redirect in the new window in other page!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
  } else {
    window.open("https://www.yahoo.com");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Se quiser abrir em _blank use:

```html
window.open("https://www.google.com", '_blank');
```